# Umbraco xslt navigation query

Tags: xslt, umbraco

Struggling a bit with my Umbraco xslt navigation macro.  I've got the top level working, but now realize I need a second level, and also for each top level LI to have a unique class (and a selected class where appropriate).  Can anyone help me out?

This is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:variable name="level" select="1"/>    
<xsl:template match="/">    
<ul id="section_navigation">
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById('1137')/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
  <li>
    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
    </a>
    <xsl:if test="count(./child::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']) &gt; 0">
      <div class="sub">
        <ul>
          <xsl:for-each select="./child::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
            <li>
              <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
              </a>
            </li>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>    
</xsl:template>
```

and here's the result I'm looking for:

```
<ul id="section_navigation">
        <li class="pal"><a href="/Pal">Pal</a></li>
        <li class="memo"><a href="/memo">Memo</a>
            <div class="sub">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/memo/latest">Latest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/memo/history">History</a></li>>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="questions"><a href="/questions">Questions</a></li>
        <li class="office"><a href="/office">Office</a></li>
        <li class="mail"><a href="/mail">Mail</a>
            <div class="sub">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/mail/mailbox">MailBox</a></li><li><a href="/mail/new-message">New Message</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="jobs"><a href="/jobs">jobs</a>
            <div class="sub">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/jobs/all">All</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/jobs/magazine">Magazine</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Not sure if the sub-section within div class="sub" is right.  Maybe if I add the selected class to the parent LI though it might work.

I thought for the LI class, I could use the page Name and try something like `<li class="{@Name}">`, but had no success with that.  Any ideas there would be appreciated too.

Let me know if any more info would be useful.

Many thanks

Comment: This doesn't resemble a proper question: 1. What is actually asked? 2. The source XML document isn't provided. 3. The wanted result from the transformation isn't provided. 4. No requirements are specified that the transformation should implement.

Comment: 1. The code in it's present state doesn't work to display a 2-level menu.  My question is can someone help me to make it work.  It works for a single menu.  2.  What source XML?  3. Good point - now added to main question.  4. I'm not sure what you're looking for here.  Thanks

Comment: e-on: These are questions that everybody trying to understand your post will ask. As a start, people need to have the XML document, the XSLT code and to be able to perform the transformation and repro the reported result. As of now this question is in undefined state.

Comment: Where do I find the XML document? This is my first outing with xslt so apologies if I should know all this

Comment: e-on: A transformation is applied on an XML document. If you don't know on what XML document your transformation is applied, then you don't know at all what you are doing, and even you don't know what you *have* to do.

Comment: FFS. Jog on Dimitre. This is a Umbraco Xslt macro that is embedded in the master page. There is no xml involved, unless it's hidden away in a secret place.

Comment: e-on, There *is* XML involved -- you can easily see it with a single `<xsl:copy-of select="/"/>`

Comment: @e-on, @Dimitre - There is XML, but Umbraco doesn't make it transparent within it's interface, so it's up to the user to visualise the XML depending on what Document Types and Properties they've created. However, without us knowing these details it's tough for us to answer. Every time something is published, it caches the data into an XML file that can be (by default) found at `/App_Data/umbraco.config`. If not there, check your `web.config` for the `umbracoContentXML` key, which represents the location. This is the XML file that all the XSLTs run off.

Comment: @GoranMottram: I am not an Umbraco user/developer. I (and anyone else who wishes to help with the transformation) need to know the detailes listed in my previous comment (1,2,3). Without this information, there is no problem defined and thus there is no solution (a solution solves a particular problem).

Comment: @e-on - By the way, try `<li class="{name(.)}" />` for the class part of your question.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - No worries, mate. I was just acting as a kind of mediator and giving a little background info on Umbraco. Even with this knowledge, it's tough to answer without more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to try the following Umbraco package:

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/cogworks-flexible-navigation

You can view the XSLT for it to see how it works or just use it our of the box (I think it will meet your needs).

In terms of your original question, it sounds as if you need some reference information on Umbraco its self.

The best place for that is the [Umbraco wiki](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki)