# Umbraco Cogworks Flexible Navigation - How to exclude document types

Tags: xslt, umbraco

Can someone tell me how to exclude document types from the Cogworks Flexible Navigation?

How do I allow for an array or list of document types to be excluded from the navigation?

Note: I do not want to use "umbracoNaviHide" as I want document types to be excluded, I do not want to add a true/false checkbox to my document type and then manually check them all.

Cogworks - Flexible Navigation: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/cogworks-flexible-navigation

Related post: [Umbraco xslt navigation query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886484/umbraco-xslt-navigation-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether you are using the Razor version or the XSLT version. For XSLT, you would add a `*[name()!='MyDoctypeAlias' or name()!='MyOtherDoctypeAlias']` to the "match" attribute on the nodeIterator template in the XSLT file.

For the Razor version, inside the nodeIterator helper, I would define as follows:

```
List<string> listOfDoctypesToExclude = new List<string>() { "MyDoctypeAlias", "MyOtherDoctypeAlias" };
if (!listOfDoctypesToExclude.Contains(currentNode.NodeTypeAlias) {
  // continue with render
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm using the XSLT version. You helped steer me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this works well as a short cut, but I'd still like someway of creating an array or list of excluded document types.

First hide ancestorSelected state:

```
<!--Is the node a branch? i.e. are there children and is it in the colletion of ancestor nodes -->
    <xsl:variable name="isBranch">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc][@id = $currentNodeID]/child::*[@isDoc][name() != 'MyDoctypeAlias']">1</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Then hide the child nodes (hasChildren):

```
<xsl:variable name="hasChildren">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="./*[@isDoc][name() != 'MyDoctypeAlias']">1</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: You can, if you want, take the C# code I've written for you, put it in a method that returns bool in a class in the App_Code folder, add the [XsltExtension] attribute above the "public class" declaration, then change your attribute to [MyXsltExtensionClass:MyCustomMethod(name()) = false] in your XSLT. C# and XSLT can inter-operate, and XSLT extensions in the App_Code folder can be picked up at runtime in Umbrco. Using inline XSLT collections for parameter checking is a bit of a pain, in my view.
Also, would you mind making the question as the answer if it helped you out?